# Unable to load Vuejs application on Azure after deployment

Tags: visual-studio, azure, vue.js, azure-pipelines

I am attempting to deploy a simple Vue.js application (a landing page) to an Azure web app service resource through the Azure Devops pipeline service. I have the build and release pipelines running "successfully" but I'm seeing a 404 on the resource after deployment.

I'm also using Visual Studio for development of this application, so I have a solution file with a project for the Vue code inside of that.

**Project Structure**

```
MySolution
--MyProject
----src
----dist
```

**azure-pipelines.yaml configuration**

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
  workingDirectory: 'MyProject'
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: |
    npm build
  workingDirectory: 'MyProject'
  displayName: 'npm build'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: 'MyProject/dist/**'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs: 
    pathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    ArtifactName: 'dist' # output artifact named dist
```

When the copy files task is ran, it's preserving the directory structure inside of the artifact like so:

```
dist
--MyProject
----dist
------index.html
```

I can see the artifact being created in the pipeline (named 'dist') and being deployed to the resource. **I believe** the issue is coming from the Copy Files and Publish tasks in the azure-pipelines.yaml file as that same directory structure is under the wwwroot on the resource (wwwroot -> dist -> MyProject -> dist), rendering the resource unable to find the index.html file.

I can see two possible solutions here:

1. Remove the directory structure in the artifact so that the index.html file is at the artifact root.
2. Update the IIS config to inform it of the proper location of the index.html file.

Most of my background is in AWS and apache/nginx so I'm a bit lost on how to implement either of these options in the Microsoft world. Any guidance is appreciated as I've been banging my head bloody on this for a few hours now. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a few hours away and realizing I was over thinking this, the answer to this question is both options presented above

**Step 1**

1. Remove the directory structure in the artifact so that the index.html file is at the artifact root.

There is an additional option you can add to the CopyFiles step in the build pipeline to denote the source folder. Doing so will copy the files in the structure from that point on, while preserving any subfolder structure if you're using the double wildcard character '**'.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'MyProject/dist'
    Contents: |
      **
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```

Will result in a directory structure in the artifact of

```
dist
-- index.html
```

**Step 2**

2. Update the IIS config to inform it of the proper location of the index.html file.

I also needed to setup a web.config file with the rewrite rule to use the index.html file (as Azure was trying to create a node.js web.config file by default when no web.config file was present). This config file needed to be in the root directory of the artifact as well, so I added a second CopyFile task to do that before the main CopyFile task to the build staging directory.

```
  displayName: 'Copy web.config to: MyProject/dist'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: 'MyProject'
    Contents: |
      **/web.config
    TargetFolder: 'MyProject/dist'
```